# Adding event in the resource in dayview in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

My problem is that I am trying to create an event in one of my resources. I have got the ResourceId based on where I click in the view. However, when I try to add the event, it fails to display on the view. I am at a total loss.

I am using fullCcalendar 3.6.1. Here is my code:

```
select: function(start, end, event, view, resource) {
  alert(resource.id)
  var resourceID = resource.id;
  // Display the modal.
  // You could fill in the start and end fields based on the parameters
  $('#NewCalModal').modal('show');
  $('#NewCalModal').find('#Date').val(dateTimedd);
  $('#NewCalModal').find('#starts-at').val(dateTimett);
  $('#NewCalModal').find('#Location').val(roomLocation);
  // Whenever the user clicks on the "save" button om the dialog
  $('#save-event').on('click', function() {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var storedate = $('#Date').val();
    var starttime = storedate + ' ' + $('#starts-at').val(); // whitespace allow the time to be read
    var endtime = storedate + ' ' + $('#ends-at').val();
    if (title) {
      var eventData = {
        title: title,
        start: starttime,
        end: endtime,
        resourceId: resourceID

      };
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

    // Clear modal inputs
    $('.modal').find('input').val('');

    // hide modal
    $('.modal').modal('hide');

  });

},
```

Here is the view of the calendar:

[image]

Comment: any errors in your console when you try to do this? Have you checked that `eventData` looks like you expect, before you add it (i.e. correct dates, resource ID etc)? You haven't told us anything you've done to try and debug or narrow down the problem on this.

Comment: BTW, every time `select() ` runs, you add a new "click" event to your button (via `$('#save-event').on('click', function() {`) without removing previous click events. This might lead to multiple click events firing (and multiple events created, repeatedly) when you click this for the 2nd, 3rd, ...nth time. Setting an event handler on an element doesn't remove any previous handlers, it just adds another handler as well as the existing ones. I would do `$('#save-event').off("click").on('click', function() {` to remove old handlers and ensure this doesn't cause problems.

Comment: Another observation: `$('#NewCalModal').find('#Date').val(dateTimedd);
  $('#NewCalModal').find('#starts-at').val(dateTimett);`. Where do `dateTimedd` and `dateTimett` come from in this code? They aren't mentioned before this point, in your snippet. They also seem to have no relation to the `start` date passed into the callback, which represents the date/time the user clicked on. Nor do you appear to make use of the end date/time which the user clicked on - instead you force the event to start and end on the same day, which may not have been the user's intention...

Comment: ...because, depending on the view you're using, an event can be dragged across multiple days. I wonder if this disconnect between the dates used and the dates clicked on is related to your bug - the event doesn't seem to be appearing because you're adding it to the wrong date, perhaps? Like I said, debugging your code using your brower's tools and seeing what actual data you're passing into fullCalendar would help to determine whether this is a related problem, or not.

Comment: datetimedd and dateTimett are from my modal.

Comment: "datetimedd and dateTimett are from my modal". No, they're JS variables. Where do you instantiate them? Have you checked in the console to see that they're defined? If they're "from the modal" as you say, then why are you using them to _set_ values _into_ the modal? Makes no obvious sense. And you haven't answered any of my other questions or queries. If that's the best response you can give to all the stuff I wrote above then I'm not going to be able to give you much help. It sounds like maybe you need to learn how to debug JS code using your browser's tools before you go further.